# RestKit as part of static library / subproject

Tags: objective-c, xcode, static-libraries, restkit

I am developing my own static library which is a sub-project of an iOS application (which I will call MyApp).  This library (which I will call MySDK) provides a set of objects which are implementations of JSON structures returned from a RESTful web service.  I am trying to use RestKit to handle the mapping between my web service and the objects in MySDK.

Prior to adding RestKit to MySDK, I had MySDK as a sub-project of MyApp, and everything compiled fine.

Then, I closed MyApp and opened the MySDK project.  I added RestKit to MySDK project following the instructions here: https://github.com/RestKit/RestKit/wiki/Installing-RestKit-v0.20.x-as-a-Git-Submodule.  Then, in one of MySDK's .h files, I added the line:

```
#import <RestKit/RestKit.h>
```

And I changed the line:

```
@interface MySDKObject : NSObject  { /*...*/ }
```

to

```
@interface MySDKObject : NSObject<RKObjectLoaderDelegate>  { /*...*/ }
```

Everything compiled fine.  Then, I closed MySDK project and reopened MyApp project.  The project navigator showed this relationship between the projects:

- My App

  - MySDK

    - RestKit

In the code editor I now get this error:

```
#import <RestKit/RestKit.h> 'RestKit/RestKit.h' file not found
```

Oddly, in the Issue Navigator, this error message is reported under the My App target.